# jquery datatables, How do I insert dropdown into table cell

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

Im using jquery datatables.I have a button and table with 3 columns. When I click the button a row will get inserted to a table with 3 values. However I would like to make third column as dropdown so that when button is clicked, a row will be inserted and user can select from dropdown in third column. Im not able to figure out how to do that. Below is the code

```
var table = $('#sampletable').DataTable();

$('#add_btn').click (function() {
    table.row.add([
        "value 1",
        "value 2",
        "need a dropdown with value 1-10 here"]).draw(false);
});
```

Comment: I think datatables is fine with html markup. Did you try adding `<select></select>` into the third column?

Comment: yes, but the problem is when I read table values using table.column(2).data()  It give me <select></select> as a text.

Comment: Maybe try it with [Column Rendering](https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/column_render.html)

Answer (score 1):

you can add new row to your datatable **tbody** like this, insure your table  have tbody tag ,if not  you can add this content after last row ;

```
var content =[];
content.push("<tr>");
 {
    content.push("<td>temp data</td>");
    content.push("<td>temp data</td>");
    content.push("<td>");
    {
        content.push("<select>");
         {
            content.push("<option>temp data </option>");
            content.push("<option>temp data </option>");
         }
        content.push("</select>");
    }
    content.push("</td>");
 }
content.pus("</tr>");



$("#yourTableID tobdy").append(content.join(""));
```

Comment: This may be applicable for DOM tables, but is certainly **not** the way to insert a row in dataTables. The row will simply disappear when the table is redrawn.